# Can't insert into phpmyadmin WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I just upgraded my Win7 32bit to Win7 64bit. Then I installed Wamp. The problem is I can't insert data into my database. The code is tested and works fine in server and it's the same code I've use in Win7 32bit.

Is there any setting that I misslook when installing wamp?

Comment: what is the error ??

Comment: post the image where you face problem

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI there is no error

Comment: Are you using the `mysqli_` database extension? And did you install a version of WAMPServer that has PHP7 **where the `mysqli_` database extension has been removed??**

Comment: PS: `MYSQL` is a the database. `phpMyAdmin` is a tool written in PHP that makes fiddling with MYSQL databases easier, or so the makers claim

Answer (score -1):

according to me xampp is best than the wamp... thorough xampp you can easily create database and easily run server and you can also work with wrodpress through xampp here are some steps to isntall xampp easily without any confusion visit xamppsol.blogspot.com

Comment: I just installed xampp. Yes, the code is working without any changes. Do you have any idea why it does'nt work in wamp?

Comment: Does the XAMPP you installed come with an old PHP 5.6 and the WAMPServer come with PHP7?